# View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) stops working after after starting another activity only if that view was not visible before on Android API <28

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, interstitial

I am making a simple game for Android. I have a number of views with buttons that are set to visibility to gone in the layout and when I want to show them I just set visibility to visible. 
Here is the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_design"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MenuLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="Main Menu" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Op1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="contin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="Continue" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Op2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="restart"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="New Game" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Sound"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="sound"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="Sound" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Settings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="settings"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="Settings" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/GameOver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_design"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Score"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="23dip"
            android:text="Your Score:" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HighScore"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="HighScore:" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LeaveGameOver"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="leaveGameOver"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="Main Menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This works flawlessly when triggered by user. When its triggered by the game itself in a different thread I have to use runOnUiThread:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Menu.showHighscore(score,original);
    }
});
```

Here is showHighscores:

```
public static void showHighscore(int s, int hs) {

    gameOver = act.findViewById(R.id.GameOver);
    System.out.println("Visiblity: " + gameOver.getVisibility());
    score.setText("Your Score: " + s);
    highScore.setText("HighScore: " + hs);
    gameOver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    System.out.println("NORMAL HIGHSCORE");
    System.out.println("Visiblity: " + gameOver.getVisibility());

}
```

This worked fine. There are no problems if I go to another app and back. But problems appeared when I added features that start other activities: rate app, consent menu and interstitial ads.

There are no problems on Android 9 (API 28), but on older Android versions starting from API 27 and down I have problems with certain UI updates not happening:

- For example the above code (showHighscores) will not make the GameOverMenu menu appear, even though its status changes to visible.
- If I set it to invisible instead of gone in the xml file OR if I show it and hide before the problem is triggered, it WILL appear, but it will look like setText didn't work.

Here is what can trigger the problem:

- Showing consent form will always trigger it, regardless when the code below is executed (even in onCreate):

```
    public void displayConsentForm() {
        URL privacyUrl = null;
        try {
            // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
            privacyUrl = new URL("https://r.flycricket.io/privacy.html");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle error.
        }

        consentForm = new ConsentForm.Builder(context, privacyUrl)
                .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                        consentForm.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                        // Consent form was displayed.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormClosed(ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                        // Consent form was closed.
                        if(userPrefersAdFree==true)
                        {
                            startBuy();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).setConsentStatus(consentStatus);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                        // Consent form error.
                    }
                })
                .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withAdFreeOption()
                .build();

        consentForm.load();

    }
```

- Rate App feature will trigger it, but only if it was triggered by user interaction. If I put the same code at the end of onCreate so it executes when the program starts it DOES NOT trigger the problem:

```
    public void rateApp(View v) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
        // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
        goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        try {
            startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName())));
        }
    }
```

- Showing an interstitial also triggers it. I wasn't able to confirm whether it causes problem when in onCreate, because at that point it didn't load yet.

I think this has something to do with starting new activity and coming back from it. I don't have this problem when I pause and resume the game.

These are my onPause and onResume:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //Menu.pause();

    Units.kill=true;

    System.out.println("Killing");

    sound.stopSounds();


    while(true) {
        try {
            animThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }

    animThread=null;
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

    Units.kill = false;

    animThread = new AnimationThread(this);

    animThread.setDaemon(true);
    animThread.setPriority(8);
    animThread.start();

    if(FullscreenActivity.sound.beam==true)FullscreenActivity.sound.startCannon();


    //if(Units.showAds==true && billingClient.isReady()) checkPurchases();

}
```

I tried to put onPause code at the beginning of displayConsentForm and onResume code into onConsentFormClosed but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: in `showHighscore()` try by setting `gameOver Visibility` before updating your `Text Views`.

Comment: I tried. Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Apparently it is caused by the following code in onResume

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

Is there a way around?

Comment: `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`  should be used before first call to `setContentView()` or `getDecorView`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rishabh pointed out, I shouldn't have had `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);` after `setContentView()`. That's what was causing the problems.